# difference between EntryPoint and handler in Spring Security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization

In Spring Security, when it comes to authentication, `AuthenticationExeption` occurs, and I know that logic such as redirection is performed through `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. And `Authorization exception` throws `AccessDeniedException` and `AccessDeniedHandler` handles it.

However, both of these are objects that are responsible for processing logic for specific exceptions, so I don't know why they are created as objects with different names, **EntryPoint** and **Handler**. The function to override when inheriting EntryPoint and the function to implement when inheriting Handler are even the same form.

```
public interface AuthenticationEntryPoint {

void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException;
```

}

```
public interface AccessDeniedHandler {

void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException)
        throws IOException, ServletException;
```

}

Why does Spring Security not handle exceptions with a single object called handler, but separate Entrypoint objects? I'm curious about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different names for two different uses cases:

- entrypoint: if you are not logged in (authentication)
- access denied: if you are not allowed to access a ressource (authorization)

See [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter):

> **Handling Security Exceptions**
>
> The `ExceptionTranslationFilter` allows translation of `AccessDeniedException` and `AuthenticationException` into HTTP responses.
>
> `ExceptionTranslationFilter` is inserted into the FilterChainProxy as one of the Security Filters.
>
> The following image shows the relationship of `ExceptionTranslationFilter` to other components:
>
> [image]
>
> 1. First, the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` invokes `FilterChain.doFilter(request, response)` to invoke the rest of the application.
> 2. If the user is not authenticated or it is an `AuthenticationException`, then Start Authentication.
>
>    - The SecurityContextHolder is cleared out.
>    - The `HttpServletRequest` is saved so that it can be used to replay the original request once authentication is successful.
>    - The `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is used to request credentials from the client. For example, it might redirect to a log in page or send a `WWW-Authenticate` header.
> 3. Otherwise, if it is an `AccessDeniedException`, then Access Denied. The `AccessDeniedHandler` is invoked to handle access denied.
>
> If the application does not throw an `AccessDeniedException` or an `AuthenticationException`, then `ExceptionTranslationFilter` does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

**EntryPoint** (`AuthenticationEntryPoint`) handles authentication exception and **Handler** (`AccessDeniedHandler`) handles authorisation exception.

I think it is more a code design decision about the [granularity of the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455705/how-do-you-determine-how-coarse-or-fine-grained-a-responsibility-should-be-whe), and the author decided to have a more fine-grained interface such that it is more [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) as authentication and authorisation are really different things.